# What's exactly body means in DKIM

Tags: email, dkim

Normally a mail will send both html part and plain text part, like this:

> ... Headers ...
>
> This is a multi-part message in MIME
>   format.
>
> --q17TlmNAFniw=_?: Content-Type: text/plain;  charset="us-ascii"
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>
> ... Text content ...
>
> --q17TlmNAFniw=_?: Content-Type: text/plain;  charset="us-ascii"
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>
> ... Html content ...
>
> --q17TlmNAFniw=_?:--

In dkim, the body to hash measn which one?

- All content after ... Headers ...
- All content after ... Headers ... but without content boundary
- Html/Text Content with MIME Headers
- HTml/Text Content without MIME Headers

Comment: Section 3.4.3 and 3.4.4 might help you https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4871.txt

Answer (score 3):

When using the 'relaxed' DKIM canonicalization algorithm I have found that hashing the following results in a [validating](http://www.port25.com/domainkeys/) body hash and a valid DKIM signature for multipart/alternative emails (`<CRLF>` added for clarity, note the trailing `<CRLF>`)

```html
--boundary<CRLF>
Content-Type: text/plain<CRLF>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable<CRLF>
<CRLF>
foo<CRLF>
--boundary<CRLF>
Content-Type: text/html<CRLF>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable<CRLF>
<CRLF>
bar<CRLF>
--boundary--<CRLF>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the canonicalization algorithm you are using. See http://www.dkim.org/specs/rfc4871-dkimbase.html#canonicalization